Worldsheet gauge fields in string theory?
Can we introduce a worldsheet gauge field in Polyakov action?
In superstring theory we need to be careful about anomaly cancellation, supersymmetry which fix the field content of worldsheet. Is there a way to introduce worldsheet gauge fields in superstring or bosonic string in a consistent way? what are the consequences of these deformations?
There is no propagating degrees of freedom for a 2d gauge field, but is this a real problem?

How would you couple the gauge field to the worldsheet fields? As far as I know there isn't a global $U(1)$ symmetry you can gauge. Unless you make some of the spacetime coordinates complex, but naively that seems like it would cause problems.

@Andrew, you can consider $Z=X+iY$ and $\bar Z=X-iY$ as complex coordinates from the real ones.

Maybe not exactly what you are looking for but Topological String theory does something like this (e.g. look at supersymmetric gauged sigma models) where a gauged theory on the worldsheet is introduced as a string theory. However  don't remember if you can relate this directly back to the Polyakov action (you probably can through the metric $g$ being induced on the moduli space of solution of the sigma model however I don't remember the full details.

This paper seems to address the question: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0550321389900059

@Andrew, Thanks a lot Andrew.
